# deduplicating a sequence in clojure

Tags: clojure

I need to define a function which takes a sequence and some functions which act on elements inside the sequence. It returns a sequence from the old sequence where the elements with duplicate function values are removed.

```
(defn dedup [seq & functions] ...)
```

for example, if

```
(f1 1) = 'a'
(f1 2) = 'a'
(f1 3) = 'c'
(f1 4) = 'd'

(f2 1) = 'za'
(f2 2) = 'zb'
(f2 3) = 'zc'
(f2 4) = 'zb'
```

then

```
(dedup [1 2 3 4] f1 f2)
```

returns a sequence of (1 3)

how do I do it?

EDIT:
edited the test values so as not to create misunderstanding

EDIT:
Below is the (not so functional) implementation for the case of only 1 function

```
(defn dedup [seq f]
  (loop [values #{} seq1 seq seq2 '()]
    (let [s (first seq1)]
      (if (nil? s)
        (reverse seq2)
        (let [v (f s)]
          (if (contains? values v)
            (recur values (rest seq1) seq2)
            (recur (conj values v) (rest seq1) (conj seq2 s))))))))
```

Comment: Clarification sorry, I meant to say there should be no repetition of a function's value, but two functions may have the same value.

Comment: your question is still unclear.  i have no idea why you exclude 2 but not 1 from the first set of functions.  they both are associated with a duplicate ("a") from what i can see.

Comment: it's fine to exclude any one of them

Answer (score 3):

your example seems to contradict the text - it is returning values where the two functions agree.

```
(defn dedup [seq & fns]
  (for [s seq :when (apply = (map #(% s) fns))] s))

(dedup [1 2 3 4] 
  #(case % 1 "a" 2 "a" 3 "c" 4 "d") 
  #(case % 1 "a" 2 "b" 3 "c" 4 "b"))
(1 3)
```

maybe that's a little too compact?  `#(... % ...)`  is equivalent to `(fn [x] (... x ...))` and the `map` in `dup` runs over the functions, applying them all to the same value in the sequence.

you could also test with

```
(dedup [1 2 3 4] {1 "a" 2 "a" 3 "c" 4 "d"} {1 "a" 2 "b" 3 "c" 4 "b"})
(1 3)
```

ps i think maybe the confusion is over english meaning.  "duplicate" means that a value repeats.  so "a" "a" is a duplicate of "a".  i *suspect* what you meant is "multiple" - you want to remove entries where you get multiple (distinct) values.

pps you could also use `filter`:

```
(defn dedup [seq & fns] 
  (filter #(apply = (map (fn [f] (f %)) fns)) seq))
```

where i needed to write one anonymous function explicitly because you can't nest `#(...)`.

Comment: Clarification: sorry, I meant to say there should be no repetition of a function's value, but two functions may have the same value. 2 is taken out because f1 returns the same value on 1 and 2. 4 is taken out because f2 returns the same value on 2 and 4. Ah that makes the question harder!